# AngularJS Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined Error

Tags: angularjs

Now in the compileNodes function in a sub function in the angular code, there are these lines:

```
} else if (childLinkFn) {
  childLinkFn(scope, node.childNodes, undefined, boundTranscludeFn);
}
```

In my custom tabs directive, I am getting the error : Cannot read  property 'childNodes' of undefined : when trying to manually compile the template for the directive (in order to dynamically add click functionality to the tabs) with this code:

```
nucleusAngular.directive('nagTabs', ['$timeout', '$http', '$compile', 'nagDefaults', function($timeout, $http, $compile, nagDefaults){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      options: '=nagTabs'
    },
        compile: function() {
            return {
                pre: function(scope, element, attributes) {
                    var template = $('<div />').append($(element).html());
                    scope.options = nagDefaults.getTabsOptions(scope.options);

                    template.find('.tabs .tab').each(function(key, value) {
                        template.find('.tabs .tab:nth-child(' + (key + 1) + ')').attr('ng-click', 'switchTab(\'' + $(this).data('tab') + '\')');
                    });

                    element.html($compile(template)(scope));
                    $(element).addClass('nag-tabs');
                },
                post: function(scope, element, attributes) {
                    var $element = $(element);
                    scope.switchTab = function(tab) {
                        if(angular.isNumber(tab)) {
                            //todo: this should work
                            //tab = $(element).find('.tabs li:nth-child(' + tab + ')').data('tab');
                            tab = $(element).find('.tabs .tab:nth-child(' + (tab + 1) + ')').data('tab');
                    }

                        $(element).find('.tabs .tab').removeClass('active');
                        $(element).find('.tabs .tab[data-tab="' + tab + '"]').addClass('active');

                        $(element).find('.tab-content-item').removeClass('active');
                        $(element).find('.tab-content-item[data-tab="' + tab + '"]').addClass('active');
                    }

                    //load the default tab
                    $timeout(function(){scope.switchTab(scope.options.defaultTab);}, 0);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div nag-tabs="tabsOptions">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li data-tab="html" ng-click="switchTab('html')">HTML</li>
        <li data-tab="javascript" ng-click="switchTab('javascript')">JavaScript</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div data-tab="html" class="tab-content-item">
            html...
        </div>
        <div data-tab="javascript" class="tab-content-item">
            javascript...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now maybe I am not compiling the template correctly however I have tried every single way I can think of to compile the template and I either get the error I mentioned or the functionality just does not work.  After reading around it seems like this error can comes up with having an empty text node.  Since I tried everything I could think of in my code, I went into the angular code and modified the three line to look like this (I only modified the first line):

```
} else if (childLinkFn && node) {
  childLinkFn(scope, node.childNodes, undefined, boundTranscludeFn);
}
```

This verifies that the node actually exists to see if it should call the childLinkFn (while I am not 100% sure the effect of this change, it would seem if node does not equal something, the childLinkFn should not be executed).  With this code in place, my tabs code works perfectly (and I have not noticed any other issues in my other directives).  I then cloned the angular.js repository and applied this change, built angular, and then executed the unit tests and end 2 end tests and they all passed.

My question is am I doing something wrong in how I am compiling the template for the tabs of should I submit this code change as a pull request (note I am working on the 1.1.3 version)?

Comment: Is the error happening in IE or Chrome or all?
Also how does the tag look like. You need to post the entire code that is applicable or post a JSFiddle.

Comment: Added requested code and the error happens in all browsers without my change to the angular code and it works fine in all browsers with my changes in the angular code

Comment: makes more sense to just do compiling in `pre` and add handlers and do manipulation in `post`. Try just passing html strings into `$compile`. Create a live demo

Comment: @charlietfl: I am adding event handlers in the pre before I do the $compile because I can't add ng-click events after the template has been compiled (and it seems counter productive to use something like jQuery events within a AngularJS).

Comment: why can't you add them after? `angular.element` is same before or after whether `jQuery` is included or not

Comment: @charlietfl: Adding elements is not the problem, it's adding the ng-click attribute.  From my understanding the only way to get directives to work properly (like ng-click) is to have them into the html that is passed to $compile.  When I try to just add the ng-click attribute in the post after the $compile, clicking on those element does nothing.

Comment: ok  I didn't look that close, thought it was event handlers being added.... where's the demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I have switched the format for the directive.  Not exactly sure how this works and returning an object with pre/post does not but it does work.  The directive code now looks like this:

```
nucleusAngular.directive('nagTabs', ['$timeout', '$http', '$compile', 'nagDefaults', function($timeout, $http, $compile, nagDefaults){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
scope: {
  options: '=nagTabs'
},
    compile: function(element, attributes, transclude) {
  $(element).find('.tabs .tab').each(function(key, value) {
    $(element).find('.tabs .tab:nth-child(' + (key + 1) + ')').attr('ng-click', 'switchTab(\'' + $(this).data('tab') + '\')');
  });

  //element.html($compile(template)(scope));
  $(element).addClass('nag-tabs');

return function(scope, element, attributes) {
    scope.options = nagDefaults.getTabsOptions(scope.options);
    var $element = $(element);
    scope.switchTab = function(tab) {
      if(angular.isNumber(tab)) {
        //todo: this should work
        //tab = $(element).find('.tabs li:nth-child(' + tab + ')').data('tab');
        tab = $(element).find('.tabs .tab:nth-child(' + (tab + 1) + ')').data('tab');
      }

      $(element).find('.tabs .tab').removeClass('active');
      $(element).find('.tabs .tab[data-tab="' + tab + '"]').addClass('active');

      $(element).find('.tab-content-item').removeClass('active');
      $(element).find('.tab-content-item[data-tab="' + tab + '"]').addClass('active');
    }

    //load the default tab
    $timeout(function(){scope.switchTab(scope.options.defaultTab);}, 0);
        }
    }
}
}]);
```